# Htaccess redirect from /example to /folder/example.php

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, redirect, static

I would like to create some temporary redirects for a few pages on a website I'm working.

I'd like to `302` redirect like this:

From: `site.com/example1/` To: `site.com/folder/example1.php`
From: `site.com/example2/` To: `site.com/folder/example2.php`

The site is based on wordpress, and I recently add a mini-site into /folder/ that has static php files. I know it's an odd redirection, but for a while I'd like serve the visitors with some an alternative content.

My problem is when I'm using:

`Redirect 302 /about/ http://site.com/folder/about.php`

When I access the `site.com/about/` link I get redirected to 
`site.com/folder/about.php/`

**The trailing slash** causes for stylesheets not to be loaded correctly.

I'd appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you're trying to do here so here is the syntax for a 302 Redirect.
This is assuming file page will have the redirect at the top.

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/about.php");
exit;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... are you changing the domain at all?  Try this:
`Redirect 302 /about/ /folder/about.php`  It worked on the example I worked up just a moment ago. Hopefully it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

on this website, you`ll find useful tips to create URL Redirections using the .htaccess file